# eclipse java code display linenumber

Tags: java, eclipse, numbers, line

what plugins do i need to install on eclipse so that .java files will show line number? how about show line number on .xml/.html as well?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There is also a simpler way: just right click on gutter (left border of your editor window in which your code resides) and enable them.. there is a specific option there.

[image]

Comment: The option is called "Show line numbers".

Answer (score 17):

Window Menu -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> check Show line numbers

Answer (score 0):

Easy click on left bar (where line numbers will show) and clikc Show line numbers.

http://prntscr.com/2znore

Answer (score 0):

What if line numbers are not displayed even after checking the line number option in Window->Preferences->Editors->Show Line Numbers checkbox. I am facing this issue.