# Eclipse: "println(__LINE__);" -- does such a preprocessor macro exist to programmatically get the code's Line Number?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, preprocessor, c-preprocessor

Note: To be clear, the question being asked is not about "How can I display line numbers in Eclipse?"  [That is answered here @ StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979809/eclipse-java-code-display-linenumber).

Goal: I want to know if Eclipse has a macro that acts as `getLineNumber()` the same way Visual Studio has the ability to use the preprocessor macro `__LINE__` to easily/universally get the line# for where this particular call to `getLineNumber()` lives on.  It's useful for knowing if a line of code was hit, without using a debugger/breakpoints.

I'd like to debug using: `println("I just hit file@line: "+__FILE__ +'@'+ __LINE__ );`

I am seeking a universal macro that can be copied and pasted to any file/any line, so that those values are known at/before compile time.  Does Java/Eclipse offer such a feature?  Possibly in an Eclipse plugin?

I can't find any info on this anywhere, I'm at a loss.  Thanks.

Comment: Um, I think what you're talking about is a language feature, not an IDE feature. `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` are predefined in C and C++ I'm not sure what the Java equivalent is.

Comment: After researching, yes you are absolutely right, it's language-wide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try that:

```
System.out.println("I just hit file@line: "+Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getFileName() +'@'+ Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getLineNumber());
```

`Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` will return an array of `StackTraceElement`, and we take the second element (the first one will be in the `Thread` class), and get the file name and line number from that.

**EDIT:** You may also want to create a static function (you can put it in an utilitary class) to do that (which will avoid the problems with the different java implementations):

```
public static void printCurrentFileAndLine() {
    final StackTraceElement[] ste = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    for (int i=0; i<ste.length; i++)
        if (ste[i].getMethodName().equals("printCurrentFileAndLine")) {
            System.out.println("I just hit file@line: "+ste[i+1].getFileName() +'@'+ ste[i+1].getLineNumber() );
            break;
        }
}
```

And you just need to call:

```
printCurrentFileAndLine();
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer Florent.  I ran this in my Android activity but I'm seeing this: `I just hit file@line: Thread.java@579`.  I will try outputting the entire getStackTrace() to see if the info I need is there

Comment: @unity303 I've tried it under Eclipse, and it worked, I think that maybe the Android java version is a little bit different, and so you may need to use `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2]`, or something like that.

Comment: exactly, I was thinking the same and after seeing the entire [] of the stack trace, I saw that element [2] was outputting perfectly for Android.  The 0th element was the Android VM, "VMStack.java@-2".  You have *TOTALLY* made my day.  Thank you!

Comment: @unity303 Glad that it worked ! I've added a static method you can use which will dynamically skip all the unneeded part of the stack, whatever the java implementation is.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful with Thread.getStackTrace() method, it's a costly method. Just use it when you really need.

For more information about that:
[How Expensive is Thread.getStackTrace()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347828/how-expensive-is-thread-getstacktrace)

Comment: Good point. I profiled it using nanotime over > 100 test cases. The shortest it took was .2ms, but longest was 1.2ms. To make it negligible in production builds, I bypass the method entirely if I am in a release build.